# how does javascript regex lazy match work?

Tags: javascript, regex

For this string

```
abc.com/file/some.png?v=123
```

how do I match `.png?` I use

```
/\..*?\?/
```

but it is matching `.com/file/some.png?`, so why is the lazy match rule not working here?

Comment: Matching always starts at the leftmost place where it can. Then it finds the shortest match starting from there.

Comment: Use `[^.]*` instead of `.*?`

Comment: This isn't just JavaScript, it's how all regexp work.

Comment: There aren't enough details to answer your question. You have to be way more specific about your input string. Otherwise we can just give you a regex that works with this *one specific example*

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of variants to this answer. I will propose matching the first file suffix after the last `/` character.

That can be done with this regex

```
/(?!.*\/)\.\w+\?/
```

---

### Explaination

```
(?!.*/)\.\w+\?
```

Options: Case insensitive; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!.*/)`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, line separator, paragraph separator)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match the character “/” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `/`
- [Match the character “.” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\.`
- [Match a single character that is a “word character” (ASCII letter, digit, or underscore only)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the question mark character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\?`

\1

- [Insert a backslash](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `\`
- [Insert the character “1” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `1`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)